# What is Solana spl-token Aux account

Tags: solana, solana-cli

What is Aux account?

I've created my own spl-token. I can mint the initial supply for my own account with my main address. I created another address and create the token account for it:

```
spl-token create-account thisismytokenid solana-wallets/new.json
```

And then I minted my spl-token to the new address like so:

```
spl-token mint thisismytokenid 1000 solana-wallets/new.json
```

The token ended up in my main account. When I run the `spl-token accounts` command, it lists two different accounts, with the latest being an Aux account. What is that? So I can't create a token account nor mint token for another address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aux accounts are non-associated token accounts, or non-canonical.

You can use multiple accounts, but there is only one associated token account per mint. It is recommended to only use the associated token account.

Comment: I see. I understand it more after playing around with it. So. apparently it's not possible to create a token account for another address.